# Use template tags in code snippets wordpress

Tags: template-tags

I'm trying to use WordPress template tags (through shortcodes) to merge the post title and url into hyperlink html code. Which looks like this:

```
<a href="[Permalink]">[Post Title]</a>.
```

Problem is the text output uses curly quotes around the "Permalink" that are not compatible with html code. I tried placing hyperlink code using template tags (shortcodes) into a code snippet box, however then the shortcodes won't run.

I would like to merge the template tags (through shortcodes) into the hyperlink html code first, then have it show up in a code snippet box. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this and it worked on my end. The shortcode itself would be [titlelink]

```
function titlelink_ssc($content = null) {

        ob_start();
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
        $titlelink_ssc = ob_get_clean();
        return $titlelink_ssc;

        }
add_shortcode("titlelink", "titlelink_ssc");
```

Comment: Why do you do the `ob_start()` and echo instead of just returning the string?

Comment: Hmm...now that you ask, I'm not sure. I guess I've just always included the ob_start() in my shortcode functions. I believe it's mainly due to the fact that most of the shortcode functions I write involve adding a secondary loop.